# Searching for file using ref number

Tags: python, linux, find, string-matching

I am trying to write a program that when prompted the user enters a Ref number and the program searches for the file which contains this ref number within it. Few things first:

The files all end with a .dpt extension and look like this:

```
PX12RUJ 
PX12RUR
PX12RUV
#PX12RUU
PX12WLJ
#PX12WLL
PX12WLK
PX12RUW
WN14YGV
WN14YGY
```

Once I have found the file I need to read its contents into an array ignoring all lines that start with a `'#'`.

**EDIT:** Code for search but output is blank, grep within linux returns correct file test.dpt

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

a = subprocess.Popen(("grep -l PX12WLK /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/*/*.dpt"),shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output = a.communicate()[0]
print output
```

**EDIT 2:** Sorted it in the end for anyone interested here's how:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call


s_REG=raw_input('Please enter Reg number: ')

a = Popen(["grep -l %s /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/*/*.dpt" %s_REG],shell=True, stdout = PIPE)
FILE_DIR = a.communicate()[0]
FILE_DIR=FILE_DIR.rstrip('\n')

FILE=open("%s" %FILE_DIR , 'r')
# Read File into array
LINES = FILE.read().split('\n')
# Remove Blank Lines and whitespace
LINES = filter(None, LINES)
# Ignore any lines that have been commented out
LINES = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), LINES)
FILE.close()

# Call the CrossRef Processor for each Reg to make sure for no differences
for I in range(len(LINES)):
   call(["/shares/optiload/prog/indref.sh", "%s" %LINES[I]])
```

Comment: I would suggest having a look through the [io documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call


s_REG=raw_input('Please enter Reg number: ')

a = Popen(["grep -l %s /shares/MILKLINK/PPdir/*/*.dpt" %s_REG],shell=True, stdout = PIPE)
FILE_DIR = a.communicate()[0]
FILE_DIR=FILE_DIR.rstrip('\n')

FILE=open("%s" %FILE_DIR , 'r')
# Read File into array
LINES = FILE.read().split('\n')
# Remove Blank Lines and whitespace
LINES = filter(None, LINES)
# Ignore any lines that have been commented out
LINES = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), LINES)
FILE.close()

# Call the CrossRef Processor for each Reg to make sure for no differences
for I in range(len(LINES)):
   call(["/shares/optiload/prog/indref.sh", "%s" %LINES[I]])
```